# Insert data in SQL using shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I have a table which has 3 columns:

`Year--------- |------ Start_seq ----- |--------- End_Seq-----------`

I want to populate the data in such a way that:

1 - If year is present i.e if 2016 is present in year then only update the end_seq

i.e for `year` `start_seq` and `end_seq`

2 - If the year is not present then insert the entry for that year in that table

I have to handle all this in a shell script.

I am able to get this far:

```
   Declare variable_out varchar2(5);

     begin

      SELECT count(*) into variable_out FROM ar9_glext_report_seq WHERE year=2017 

        if variable_out ==1
        update ar9_glext_report_seq
        set FileSeqNumberEnd = FileSeqNumberEnd +1
        where year=2017
        commit ;

        else

         insert into ar9_glext_report_seq values (2017 , 0001, 0001);
         commit;
```

Please help.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is not a jobs board. This is not a place to dump a list of requirements and expect others to do it for you. You write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: i tried but not able to proceed

Comment: @Marc B Added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE statment (oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).

```
MERGE INTO ar9_glext_report_seq D
USING (SELECT newyear as y, newstart as start, newend as end FROM dual) S
ON (D.year= S.y)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.End_Seq = S.start
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.year, D.Start_Seq, D.End_Seq)
  VALUES (S.y, S.start, S.end)
```

Modify query in USING statment to select right values.
Sorry I can't test it.